# How to insert new row to bottom of Kendo Grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I know this question has been asked a number of times and I have seen the solutions and the solutions are not a fit for how I am doing it, and if there is a correct solution for the way I am doing it then I must have missed it.

Here is how I am adding a new row

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnAddNewRoom', function (e) {
    let roomGrid = $('#TabEditor').data("kendoGrid");

    roomGrid.dataSource.insert({ "RoomID": -1, "RoomName": "" + $('#txtNewRoom').val() + "", "Areas": [{ "AreaID": -1, "AreaName": "New Area" }] });
    roomGrid.refresh();
});
```

I know I can place an index for where I want it to go, like this..

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnAddNewRoom', function (e) {
    let roomGrid = $('#TabEditor').data("kendoGrid");

    roomGrid.dataSource.insert(0, { "RoomID": -1, "RoomName": "" + $('#txtNewRoom').val() + "", "Areas": [{ "AreaID": -1, "AreaName": "New Area" }] });
    roomGrid.refresh();
});
```

I have thought of one way to do it and that is to count how many rows there are then use that number to place at the bottom, but isn't there an easier way?

Comment: `let rowCount = roomGrid.dataSource.data().length;`.. then `insert((rowCount - 1),...`. It is easy, I think.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, that's pretty much what I ended up doing

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with Kendo UI Grid Configuration

"editable": {
    "mode": "inline",
    **"createAt": "bottom"**
},

Answer (score 1):

Try using `add` instead of `insert`, seems to do the trick:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
  <button onclick="addRow()">Test</button>
  
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
let a = 1;

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "age" }
  ],
  dataSource: {
   data: [
    { id: 1, name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
    { id: 2, name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
   ],
   schema:{
    model: {
     id: "id",
     fields: {
       age: { type: "number"}
     }
    }
   }
  }
});
  
  function addRow() {
    let grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.dataSource.add({ id: 0, name: "Test" + a++, age: 10 });
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```